# Why aren't the integers in the string performing the correct arithmetic operations when getting appended to a list?

Tags: python, string, list

From a string input of space-separated numbers such as `1 2 3 10 20`, the numbers are to be stored in a list.

```py
n=int(input())
x=input()
for i in range(len(x)-1):
    if x[i]!=" " and x[i+1]!=" ":
        k=x[i]*10+x[i+1]
        z.append(k)
        i=i+1
        continue
    elif x[i]!=" " and x[i+1]==" ":
        z.append(x[i])
    else:
        continue
for i in range(n):
    print(z[i])
```

It's showing that the output is:

```
1
2
3
4
11111111110
0
```

Why aren't the integers in the string performing the correct arithmetic operations when getting appended to the list?

Comment: What's the question?!

Comment: Provide your  [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

`x[i]` is a string, not a number. When you multiply a string, it makes copies of the string. So when `x[i] == '1'` and `x[i+1] == '0'`, `k=x[i]*10+x[i+1]` sets `k` to `'11111111110'`.

You need to do `k = int(x[i])*10 + int(x[i+1])`.

Another problem is that you can't skip over an element by doing `i = i + 1`. You're iterating over a range, so the `range()` generator will always assign the next integer in the range, regardless of what `i` is currently set to. If you want to be able to skip elements, you should use a `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < len(x)-1:
    ...
    i += 1
```

Note that your code only works for numbers with 1 or 2 digits. You should use a more general method of finding the boundaries between numbers to handle any number of digits.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar have explained the issues with your code

you can also achieve the desired result using

```py
n=int(input())
x=input().split(' ')
print(list(map(int, x)))
```